# Is it possible to specify abstract class variable type through a template?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In a API context, I'd like to minimize the classes available to the user. To that end, I'd like to generalize the type of data he has access to but specialize inputs data.

I thought of templates. However, I come from the C# world and I'm not used to possibilities and restrictions of templates in the C++ world.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
GenericAnimal<T>
bool setSubSpecies(T.EnumOfSubSpecies subSpecies)
```

```
GenericAnimal<Fish> cod;
cod.setSubSpecies(Fish.FishSubSpeciesEnum.Cod);
GenericAnimal<Mammal> cetacean;
cetacean.setSubSpecies(Mammal.MammalSubSpeciesEnum.Cetaceans);
```

The alternative would be to create a class `Fish` that derives from `GenericAnimal<T1, T2, ...>` with appropriate template classes, but as I said I'd like to avoid the profusion of classes and define `T1, T2, ...` through a unique class/structure.

Edit: code typo correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but could this perhaps be what you're looking for?

```
template <class T>
class GenericAnimal
{
public:
  bool setSubSpecies(typename T::SubSpeciesEnum)
  {
    // code here
  }
};


class Fish
{
public:
  enum SubSpeciesEnum {
    Cod, Salmon, Carp
  };
};

class Mammal
{
public:
  enum SubSpeciesEnum {
    Cetaceans, Canids, Felines
  };
};


GenericAnimal<Fish> cod;
cod.setSubSpecies(Fish::SubSpeciesEnum::Cod);

GenericAnimal<Mammal> cetaceans;
cod.setSubSpecies(Mammal::SubSpeciesEnum::Cetaceans);
```

The caveat of course is that being a template, `GenericAnimal` has to be either fully implemented in the header, or pre-specialised in your library for all types with which it can be instantiated (and the client will not be able to use it with other types).

---

To address the follow-up question from comments

> Can we have the `Fish` class be a template itself, deriving from `AnimalAttributes<T1>`, `T1` being `SubSpeciesEnum`?

That is not possible directly, because there is no way to declare `Fish::SubSpeciesEnum` before its use in the base class `AnimalAttributes`. However, workarounds exist, such as introducing an intermediary base class:

```
class FishEnum
{
public:
  enum SubSpeciesEnum {
    Cod, Salmon, Carp
  };
};

template <class EnumClass>
class AnimalAttributes : public EnumClass {
public:
  using typename EnumClass::SubSpeciesEnum;
};

class Fish : public AnimalAttributes<FishEnum>
{
};
```

Comment: Is `SubSPeciesEnum` a common class shared by all T's?
I'd like the type to depend on T. Fish would only have enums of subspecies related to fishes.

Comment: @WebRoamer It's not one typed shared by all of them. Each `T` used with `GenericAnimal` must include a nested type named `SubSpeciesEnum`, but it can be a different type for each `T`. I will expand the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean, thanks.
One more question: can we have Fish class be a template itself, deriving from AnimalAttributes<T1>, T1 being SubSpeciesEnum?
I try to do so, but get a C2061 error about the identifier SubSpeciesEnum.