# Compilation error with a dynamic_cast of a template class

Tags: c++, templates

This question follows a previous one you can find on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56574941/is-it-possible-to-specify-abstract-class-variable-type-through-a-template).
I tried to add some polymorphism on top of the template architecture without any success (see code and compilation errors below).

I tried to connect the problem with other ones based on compilation errors without any success. I identified an 'alias' definition problem with VC12 but the problem still appears with VC15.

GenericAnimal

```
template <class T>
class GenericAnimal
{
public:
    bool InstantiateAnimal(typename T::SubSpeciesEnum value);
private:
    T _attributes;
};
template <class T>
bool GenericAnimal<T>::InstantiateAnimal(typename T::SubSpeciesEnum value)
{
    AnimalAttributes<typename T::SubSpeciesEnum>& attributes = dynamic_cast<AnimalAttributes<typename T::SubSpeciesEnum>&> (_attributes);
    //int ID = attributes.InstantiateAnimal(value);
    //bool ret = ID != -1;
    bool ret = true;
    return ret;
}
```

AnimalAttributes

```
template <class EnumClass>
class AnimalAttributes : public EnumClass {
public:
    using typename EnumClass::SubSpeciesEnum;

    virtual int InstantiateAnimal(typename EnumClass::SubSpeciesEnum subSpecies) = 0;
};
```

FishEnum

```
class FishEnum
{
public:
    enum SubSpeciesEnum {
        Cod, Salmon, Carp
    };
};
```

Fish

```
#include "AnimalAttributes.h"
#include "FishEnum.h"

class Fish : public AnimalAttributes<FishEnum>
{
public:
    Fish();
    int InstantiateAnimal(FishEnum::SubSpeciesEnum subSpecies);
};

Fish::Fish()
{

}

int Fish::InstantiateAnimal(FishEnum::SubSpeciesEnum subSpecies)
{
    int ID = -1;
    // NB: no code for real instantiation [yet]

    switch (subSpecies)
    {
        case FishEnum::Carp:
        {
            ID = 0;
            break;
        }
        case FishEnum::Cod:
        {
            ID = 1;
            break;
        }
        case FishEnum::Salmon:
        {
            ID = 2;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ID;
}
```

Following compilation errors:

```
Erreur  C2516   'EnumClass' : classe de base non conform
Erreur  C2838   'SubSpeciesEnum' : nom qualifié non conforme dans une déclaration de membre 
Erreur  C2873   'SubSpeciesEnum' : un symbole ne peut pas être utilisé dans une déclaration using   
Erreur  C2838   'SubSpeciesEnum' : nom qualifié non conforme dans une déclaration de membre
Erreur  C2061   erreur de syntaxe : identificateur 'SubSpeciesEnum'
```

Comment: Compile fine for clang/gcc [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b25b8f4516964ebd).

Comment: Notice than since C++11, you might use `enum class` instead of enum inside class.

Comment: Thanks Jarod. The test would be [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d9ab59f17945fc0).
I have difficulties to understand ```'FishEnum::SubSpeciesEnum' is not a base type for type 'AnimalAttributes<FishEnum::SubSpeciesEnum>'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
template <class T>
bool GenericAnimal<T>::InstantiateAnimal(typename T::SubSpeciesEnum value)
{
    AnimalAttributes<typename T::SubSpeciesEnum>& attributes = dynamic_cast<AnimalAttributes<typename T::SubSpeciesEnum>&> (_attributes);
    int ID = attributes.InstantiateAnimal(value);
    bool ret = ID != -1;
    return ret;
}
```

with `T` = `Fish`, you have:

`T::SubSpeciesEnum` = `FishEnum::SubSpeciesEnum` (the enum).

so `AnimalAttributes<typename T::SubSpeciesEnum>` is `AnimalAttributes<FishEnum::SubSpeciesEnum>`.

and `AnimalAttributes<T>` requires that `T` has `SubSpeciesEnum`, that `FishEnum::SubSpeciesEnum` hasn't.

Comment: OK, got this. I don't have a clue however how to cast my T/Fish into an AnimalAttribute<U> in order to use the virtual function. What would be U (In reality, FishEnum but what can I use instead)?

Comment: You might do something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/942416cd7ea129eb). Not sure of the purpose of the classes but it seems more complicated than it should.

Comment: The purpose of the class would be to guide the API user. First, he needs to specify which set of sub-species he want to work with. Then, functions that need sub-species specific types will know which input they require. Animals are here just an (clumsy) example. If you have another point of view on how to do that, I'm all ears :)
Your answer is great, it both simplifies the code and fixes the cast issue.